# Как проверить открыт ли файл на Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытаюсь записать строку в файл и все работает, но когда файл открыт строка не записывается.

1. Как проверить открыт ли файл?
2. Как его закрыть и записать в него строку?

Comment: У вас есть дескриптор файла (тот, который нужно закрыть)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python

Comment: можно ли как то получить и записать этот дескриптор в переменную?
я просто совсем новачок..

Comment: я в .txt файл записываю дату. И вот я хочу что бы она туда записалась при любом развитии событий.. первая проблемма это когда файл открыт дата в нем не обновляется. вот!

Comment: Если у Вас нет этого дескриптора, а файл уже открыт. Кажется, что Вы что-то не так делаете. Зачем Вам это? В теории можно

Comment: открыт вашим приложением или сторонним?

Comment: он просто открыт мной. Это на тот случай если кто то будет просматривать этот файл в то время как будет происходить процес записывания даты в этот файл.

Comment: явно опишите, что значит "не записывается": запустите что-нибудь вроде `Path(destination_filename).write_text('text')` и ошибку (traceback) в вопрос добавьте. Явно упомяните вашу систему (Windows). В *вопросе* напишите кто открыл файл, как и с какой целью (если это ваш код делает)¶ Попробуйте писать во временный файл (`with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False) as tmpfile: tmpfile.write('text')`), а потом вызывать `Path(tmpfile.name).replace(destination_filename)`